# Remove all navigationControllers from stack and create a new navigation flow setting new window - best practices

Tags: ios, swift, memory, stack, navigationcontroller

It may be a newbie question - I have a flow which I create in app delegate setting the first window a `NavigationController` as below:

```
let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let root = SplashViewController(nibName: "SplashViewController", bundle: nil)
window.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: root)
window.makeKeyAndVisible()

self.window = window
```

This `SplashViewController` is a root of my first flow (Tutorial, signin and signup) And for each one, I create a new navControll (modal, etc)

The thing is: when this flow is done, the user come into the `HomeViewController` - Here I have to clean things up. Remove my old flow from the heap to make everything OK to 'start' the app.

I've been searching and many people use to create a new window calling the AppDelegate singleton - Is this a good practice? (I've tried but my Splash remain there) - by the way, I'm playing a video on that Splash as background.

I tried, also, do a notification to dismiss my flow, but my Splash still there..
Let me know if you need more context.

Appreciate any help! thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to define in AppDelegate function like

```
func changeRootToNewVC() {
    let newRoot = NewViewController(nibName: "NewViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.window?.rootViewController = newRoot
}
```

This will change rootViewController of current window. This is enough, you doesn't need to create new Window object.

Comment: Hi @Dzmitry, thanks for your answer! So, if I create that function o my AppDelegate and call it, must do the trick? Will this remove the other viewControllers (and navControllers) from stack? I'll try here .. Just want to know if I need do something else too..

Comment: @Gehlen Yes this is all you need to do. But there are several issues on rdar about iOS bugs when setting rootViewController by this way. So I suggest to check that your views stack resented correctly. If no then possible workaround which I sometimes use is to create your own container controller which is used as default rootViewController and presenting all other VCs in your app. And use this object to switch between view stacks.

Comment: thanks again!! I figured out what I did wrong.. I've created a protocol without setting as class, so it was strong. What was retaining my splashView. So, I'll try to create a container, looks like it is better practice.. Thanks!